# how to locally update data from firebase in flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

At the start, I fetch the data and store it in _allData:

```
late List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _allData;
late List<QueryDocumentSnapshot> _filteredData;

void fetchData() async {

  QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('games')
    .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
    .get();
  _allData = querySnapshot.docs;

  _filteredData = _allData;
  setState(() {
    _isLoading = false;
  });
}
```

The problem is that the user can also perform like on each document after which I call update on db but it's not efficient to fetch the data all over again so I want to update the fields 'likes' and 'likedby' locally. How would I do that?

I have this so far:

```
void updateLike(String gameId, bool liked, String userId) {
  print(gameId);
  print(liked);
  print(userId);
  int gameIndex = _allData.indexWhere((doc) => doc.id == gameId);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to perform a database update **and** a separate update of the local state, I recommend using [command query segregation principle](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html). In this case, that means:

1. [Using a snapshot listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen) to both get the initial data and listen to updates to that data.
2. Write the data without concern for the UI updates.

You're already doing that second part, but you'll have to change to using the `snapshots()` stream rather than `get()` to get the updates.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried doing:
    `FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('games')
        .orderBy('likes', descending: true)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
      _allData = querySnapshot.docs;
    });`
but ended up stuck on loading forever. Isn't there a simpler approach without using listeners or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does the code in the `listen` callback get executed at all? If so, you'll need to call `setState` from in there too - to ensure that Flutter knows to update the UI.